# How to make specified text red

Tags: html

Problem: I am creating a testimonials page and one of the replies is by an admin, who have a red "ADMIN" tag where the normal stars would go. I have tested the waters by removing the ending p tag, putting quotes on both the red and color tags. Nothing seems to work.

Expected Result: Testimonial profile with a red ADMIN tag on the top right corner of the box

Code:

```
  <div class="container">  
<p test-align: right; color="red";>ADMIN<p>
  <img src="pic-3.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:90px">
  <p><span>Someone.</span> TRAVEL Travel CEO.</p>
  <p>We are glad you enjoyed are service. We hope to see you again!</p>

  </div>
```

[image: Picture]

Comment: Incorrect HTML markup and inline styles, correct it to: `<p style="text-align: right; color:red;>ADMIN</p>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to place inline styles inside the `style` attribute:

`<p style="text-align: right; color:red;">`

Also: don't use equal signs (`=`) to specify styles ;-)

It will work with just that!

Answer (score 0):

Try playing around with the CSS using inspect element.

Answer (score 0):

you must use `style`, and you should learn CSS again.

```
<p style='test-align:right;color:red';>ADMIN<p>
```